# ASP.NET MVC4 ViewModel for editing certain fields. And am I doing it right? Am I missing the point of ViewModel?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, django, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

Recently I'm trying to convert from *Django* to *ASP.NET MVC 4*. One thing I don't understand is how to edit only few fields of model, and how *ViewModel* comes to this. In example I don't want to update entry creation date. `[Bind(Exclude = "Date")` somehow didn't work, furthermore I noticed that ViewModel is recommended for that. I want to show you how I did it, to you ask if it's correct and some other questions.

Model and ViewModel:

```
//Movie Model
public class Movie
{
    [Key]
    public int MovieId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string MovieTitle { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
    public DateTime MovieReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public Category MovieCategory { get; set; }
}

//MovieEdit ViewModel
public class MovieEdit
{
    [Key]
    public int MovieId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    //[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string MovieTitle { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
//
// GET: /Default1/Edit/5

public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
    if (movie == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryId", "CategoryName", movie.CategoryId);
    return View(Mapper.Map<MovieEdit>(movie));
}

//
// POST: /Default1/Edit/5

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(MovieEdit movie)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var movieToUpdate = db.Movies.Single(p => p.MovieId == movie.MovieId);
        movieToUpdate.MovieTitle = movie.MovieTitle;
        movieToUpdate.CategoryId = movie.CategoryId;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(movie);
}
```

View:

```
@model MegaTest.ViewModels.MovieEdit

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Movie</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MovieId)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MovieTitle)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MovieTitle)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MovieTitle)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", "-- Choose Category --") 
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
```

This works seems kinda strange to me.

1. Is this correct to make Edit `ViewModel` exactly the same with just less fields than Original Model, especially if at the end I save edited information this way. Is this correct?:

   `var movieToUpdate = db.Movies.Single(p => p.MovieId == movie.MovieId);
   movieToUpdate.MovieTitle = movie.MovieTitle;
   movieToUpdate.CategoryId = movie.CategoryId;
   db.SaveChanges();`
2. How is this `"ViewModel"` stuff to DRY methodology. If I did it correctly. If. When I commented `StringLenght` attribute in `EditModel`, validation does not work and raises error `"Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."`. I had to rewrite part of one model into different model, with everything including attributes. I read that some developers create `ViewModel` for every View. If this has to be done like in my example seems to me more like "Repeat Yourself" methodology than DRY.
3. Why didn't `[Bind(Exclude = "MovieReleaseDate")` work in this example? And why it is not recommended?

One last thing, in *Django* you just create `ModelForm` and exclude or include fields that you want. Then when saving model it just do "UPDATE" on fields that are included in `ModelForm`. This `ModelForm` inherits all validation attributes for selected fields... Like this:

```
class ColorsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserAdditionalData
        fields = ('show_color', 'color')
```

Am I doing something wrong in .NET?

Comment: I don't know the answers to all of your questions but wanted to give my 2 cents about view models.  I generally create view models when I have more information to send to the view than just the database model.  If there are 2 models to send, dropdowns, flags, stuff like that.  In your example you can send the main model to the view,  just don't do anything with the date.  I generally don't create a view model for using less information.  I just don't interact with the fields that I don't need.  Hopefully this helps

Comment: Ok, but how do you edit/update database entry when you want update just one or two fields? Just like I did, except you don't create ViewModel? You also take entry from database, create instance, assign new value to instance and then save?

Comment: Yes,  I think you did it exactly right.  If you are running a query that updates more fields you can pass those fields through the view putting them in a hidden field and then will come back to the controller or you can requery the database for the model, update the fields that have changed, and send back